# How does the Macau visa-on-arrival work?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, visas-on-arrival, proof-provenance-of-funds, macau

I have planned a 5-day stay in Macau two weeks from now. I have already booked and paid for my hotel for the entire stay and have return air tickets for my partner and myself. Based on my passport, I have to complete a visa-on-arrival process at the airport. In it, it asks for proof of sufficient funds (MOP5,000).

Is this a must?

Is it based on how long we'll be there, or for any period of stay?

If you're there for 1 day or 30 days, is it still 5,000?

Could you have less for a shorter stay?

How do they verify this?

Do you have to carry it in cash?

What would happen if I don't have the required amount on me?

Would I be refused entry for not having the required amount?

Also, I'm on a Temporary Residency Visa (until 2022) in China which is a visa-exempt country.

Would I qualify as a Chinese Resident, or is that just for people with Permanent Residency Permits?

Answer (score 2):

Visa-exempt entry for Macau is typically for [a maximum of 30 days for people of most nationalities](http://www.fsm.gov.mo/psp/eng/EDoN.html). The official guidelines state:

> Visitors are required to prove that they possess the vital resources
>   of **a minimum of MOP5000** for their expected period of stay in Macao

In most cases, where such requirements are described by countries, there isn't necessarily a check for every single visitor to show documents. People show this in different ways: cash, bank account statements, credit card statements etc.
In general, showing pre-booked accommodation means it's accounted for into that MOP 5000 (or other currencies, in other countries).

Basically, checking whether a visitor has sufficient funds is up to the discretion of the border office in most countries, and usually not carried out. When it *is* done, the guiding principle appears to be whether you could "plausibly" live with the amount of funds at your disposal for the length of stay. If you don't seem to have that, it's considered a risk by border officials that you'll overstay.

My experience with Macau (and Hong Kong) border officials is that they are pretty relaxed: they have one of the most permissive visa-exempt rules globally  and don't grill travellers. You didn't mention what passport you hold - but this is especially true (of not grilling travellers) if you carry travel documents from a "low-risk" country.

(A lot of  "usuallys" in the above because from experience, I've never been stopped to ask to prove sufficient funds ever - but other travellers I know have.)